# Place for doing something (word building)

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

What do I call a place where paper is unloaded by workers from trucks, in two words or less? Is there is a simple formula for making such nouns?

Comment: Usually, this is done in a *loading bay*.

Comment: 'Is there is a simple formula for making such nouns?' Attributive noun + head noun strings are common, often forming compounds, but the role of the attributive noun varies widely. Thus _coffee cake_ and _coffee morning_; _sunroof_ and _sunscreen_. The rules are: check in a dictionary to see (a) if they exist; (b) what they mean. Coming up with a new candidate usage is highly likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Loading bay**, **loading dock**, **loading zone** and **loading platform** are all names for the place where goods are loaded and unloaded. In all cases you can use *unloading* instead of *loading*, which will give some the impression that the place is only used for unloading, whereas *loading* won't necessarily give this impression (this is because *loading* is the [unmarked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness#Marked_and_unmarked_word_pairs) term here).

*Loading bay* can be shortened to *bay* without issue. *Loading dock* can be shortened to *dock*, but to the best of my knowledge that can only refer to such structures used for loading and unloading from ships. *Loading zone* and *loading platform* can't be shortened without losing this specific meaning.

Now, if you really want a two-letter word specifically for paper, perhaps *paper bay* or *paper platform* is the best option, but I'd definitely use the full term before using the shorter form.

Comment: [*dock*](https://www.google.com/search?q=dock&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) : "a platform for loading or unloading trucks or freight trains." See also, [*dock plate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_plate); used for "bridging the gap between a truck and the dock or warehouse floor" - AKA, *Shipping and Receiving*